# Variadic template, function as argument

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I would like to use a function as argument in a variadic template, why does the following not work? How do I make it work?

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
F test(F f, const Args&&... args) {
return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int simple(int i) { 
    return i; 
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << test(simple, 2); // error, 'std::forward': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

First of all, you should use forwarding references, so you need to change `const Args&&...` to `Args&&...`.

Then, `test` does not have to return `F`. So it is reasonable to use `decltype(auto)` here.

In addition to that, it makes sense to forward `f` too.

The fixed version might look like this:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) test(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[**WANDBOX EXAMPLE**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/D4Th7WMMbr1AZroS)

Comment: Why is it that when I add the 'test' function and the 'simple' function to a basic class, 'Tester', as public functions, and in main do:

Tester t;
std::cout << t.test(t.simple, 2);

It no longer works, it says it cannot find a matching overloaded function, and Tester::simple non-standard syntax; use &...

Comment: @Alexander Shortly, because `simple` becomes a member function. You cannot pass member functions to the `test` function written above. At least, you have to provide an instance on which call the member function. Look at `std::invoke` for further details: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke

Comment: @EdgarRokjān `it makes sense to forward f too.` <--- could you please explain why? The only situation I can think of is if we use a functor instead of a function pointer, so that functor might be an rvalue, but it's not the case here

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is the return type. Your `test` function returns `F` which is a function pointer. Instead change it to `auto` to automatically deduce the return type.

The second issue is that `std::forward` requires a non-const reference.

You might use trailing return type:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto test(F f, Args&&... args) -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

But `decltype(auto)` (C++14 required) is a simpler solution:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) test(F f, Args&&... args) {
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```