# Calling a variadic template function with a member function

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Based on my previous question here [Variadic template, function as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352511/variadic-template-function-as-argument)

I have ended up with a simple class below, however how do I use std::invoke or some other method to call Tester::test with Tester::simple as argument? The examples provided at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke#Example were not very helpful for me and I tried many different ways of using std::invoke.

```
class Tester {
public:
    template<typename F, typename... Args>
    decltype(auto) test(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
        return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    int simple(int i) { return i; }
};

int main()
{
    Tester t;
    std::cout << t.test(t.simple, 3); // how do you modify this line such that the code compiles?
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to modify the definition of your `test()` member function like so:

```
class Tester { 
public:
    template<typename F, typename... Args>
    decltype(auto) test(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    int simple(int i) { return i; }
};
```

We can then pass a member function pointer to `test()`, with the instance on which the method should be called as the second argument, and then the function arguments themselves:

```
int main()
{
    Tester t;
    std::cout << t.test(&Tester::simple, t, 3);
}
```

The reason this works is because `std::invoke` has a [special overload for pointers-to-members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke), such that

```
std::invoke(ptr-to-member, instance, args...);
```

is called as

```
(instance.*ptr-to-member)(args...);
```

which is exactly what we want in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Note, that [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) is a part of *C++ 17*. In case if it is not available, one might implement `test` function so that it accepts a *pointer-to-member-function* and an instance of a class:

```
template<typename F, typename T, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) test(F f, T&& t, Args&&... args) {
    return (std::forward<T>(t).*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Now `test` accepts a *pointer-to-member-function* as a first argument, an instance of a class as a second argument and an arbitrary number of additional arguments.

Then `test` might be called like:

```
Tester t;
std::cout << t.test(&Tester::simple, t, 42);
```

[**WANDBOX EXAMPLE**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KsXRhmhEeNObVaBd)

Comment: It's incompatible with non-member functions now.  Try `t.test(puts, "Hello!")`.

Comment: @HenriMenke yes, exactly. As far as I can understand, in this question OP is interested in dealing with member functions. So I've added a simple solution for member function. Now OP is free to combine solutions from both his questions to achieve the desired functionality. Or simply use `std::invoke` if his compiler lets him to do that :)

Comment: @EdgarRokjān why do you pass the object reference to a non-static member function? I tried your example without `T&& t` and replaced `std::forward<T>(t).*f` with just `this->*f`, and it worked. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention yet another possibility, you could wrap the member function call in a lambda and capture the instance `t`.  In C++14 we can use the generic lambda for that, so we don't have to specify the parameters explicitly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class Tester {
public:
    template<typename F, typename... Args>
    decltype(auto) test(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
        return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    int simple(int i) { return i; }
};

int main()
{
    Tester t;
    std::cout << t.test([&t] (auto&&... args) { return t.simple(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }, 3);
}
```